# Can't serve static files with mongoose and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

First question on StackOverflow. I'm having a problem with serving my public directory on one of my routes, it works on all other routes except my /player/:id/intro route. Here's my app.js:

```
var express=require('express'),
    app=express(),
    mongoose=require('mongoose'),
    Player=require('./models/player'),
    bodyParser=require('body-parser')

var indexRoutes=require('./Routes/index')
var conversationRoutes=require('./Routes/Conversations/index')

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://MichaelPatriot21:Werewolf18@cluster0-9umcn.gcp.mongodb.net/Ambassador?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})

app.use(indexRoutes)
app.use(conversationRoutes)

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server listening at PORT: 3000...')
})
```

Here's my index.js that has the route in question:

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express(),
    Player = require('../../models/player')

router.get('/player', function(req,res){
    Player.find({}, function(err, players){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.render('playerlist', {
                pageTitle: 'Characters',
                player: players
            })
        }
    })
})

router.get('/player/:id/intro', function (req, res) {
    Player.findById(req.params.id, function (err, player) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.render('conversations/introduction', {
                pageTitle: 'Intro',
                player: player
            })
            console.log(player)
        }
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

My file structure is: 
v3/ 
models/player.js 
node_modules/ 
public/choices-intro.css 
public/choices-intro.js 
Routes/Conversations/index.js 
Routes/index.js 
views/conversations/introduction.ejs 
views/index/home.ejs 
views/partials/footer.ejs 
views/partials/header.ejs 
views/playerlist.ejs 
app.js 
package-lock.json 
package.json

Comment: Is this the only uri you've tried with multiple path segments? Are you referencing your assets as simply `choices-intro.js`? That href is relative to the uri of the page and should be prefixed with a slash (e.g., `/choices-intro.js`) to work from any uri on your domain.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple, thank you.